# Link is not getting active even if it's open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Problems:**

1. All is working fine hover is working properly and links are opening when clicked on it, but the problem is after the link is clicked it's getting active and the color of the link is not changing.
2. I think have some javascript problem in my code, so please provide the css and javascript so that when the user clicks on a link it shold become active and color changes of the link.

   ```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/effect.css"/>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>

       <!-- START MAIN -->
   <div id="main" style="padding-left: 0px; background-color: white;">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">



       <!-- START WRAPPER -->
       <div>
           <style>
   body {
       background-color:#f1f1f1!important;
       color: #000;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
   }

   .nav-side-menu {
       border-left: 1px solid green;
       border-right:1px solid green;
       margin-left: 0px;
       overflow: auto;
       font-family: verdana;
       font-size: 15px;
       font-weight: 200;
       background-color: #f1f1f1!important;
       position: fixed;
       width: 300px;
       height: 100%;
       color: #000!important;
   }
   .nav-side-menu .brand {
     background-color: #23282e;
     color:#f1f1f1!important;
     line-height: 50px;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 16px;
   }
   .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
     display: none;
   }
   .nav-side-menu ul,
   .nav-side-menu li {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 5px 5px;
     margin: 0px;
     line-height: 35px;
     cursor: pointer;
   }
   .nav-side-menu li {
   border-bottom: 1px solid green;
   }
   .nav-side-menu li:hover {
     border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     /* color: #ffffff; */
     color:blue;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
     transition: all 1s ease;
   }

   @media (max-width: 1200px){
     .nav-side-menu {
       position: relative;
       margin-left: 0px;
       width: 100%;
       margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
       display: block;
       cursor: pointer;
       position: absolute;
       right: 10px;
       top: 10px;
       z-index: 10 !important;
       padding: 3px;
       background-color: #ffffff;
       color: #000;
       width: 40px;
       text-align: center;
     }
     .brand {
       text-align: left !important;
       font-size: 22px;
       padding-left: 20px;
       line-height: 50px !important;
     }
   }
   @media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
       display: block;
     }
   }
   .well{
   display:none;}

   .main {
       margin-left: 0px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
       font-size: 16px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
       padding: 0px 10px;
   }

   @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
       .sidenav {
           padding-top: 15px;
       }
       .sidenav a {
           font-size: 6px;
       }
   }
   </style>



   <div class="row col-lg-12">
   <div class="col">
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3" >

           <div class="nav-side-menu">
       <div class="brand">Topics</div>
       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

           <div class="menu-list">

               <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out"><c:forEach items="${tutorial}" var="tutoriallist">
                    <li style="padding-left: 20px;"><a href="<c:url value='/tutorial/afterClickingTutorialTopics?id=${tutoriallist.id} '/>" > 

                   <c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.title}">
                   <c:out value="${tutoriallist.title}" />

                   </c:if></li>
           </a>    </c:forEach></ul> 
        </div>
   </div>

   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
   <div align="justify">
       <table>
           <tbody><br>

               <%-- <c:forEach items="${tutorialdata}" var="tutoriallist"> --%>
                   <tr>
                   <table><tr><td>
                   <c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.id}">
                           <a href="<c:url value='/tutorial/afterClickingTutorialTopicsNext?id=${tutoriallist.id-1} '/>" >
                           <h4 style="color:green;font:fantasy;float:left;"><b>&lt;&lt;&lt; Prev</b></h4></a>
                   </c:if></td>
                   <td><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.id}">
                           <a href="<c:url value='/tutorial/afterClickingTutorialTopicsNext?id=${tutoriallist.id+1} '/>" >
                           <h4 style="color:green;font:fantasy;float:right;"><b>Next &gt;&gt;&gt;</b></h4></a>
                   </c:if></td></tr></table>

                       <h5 style="font-family: erdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;font-size: 29px;
                                       color: #610B38;">

                           <c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.title}">
                               <c:out value="${tutoriallist.title}" />
                           </c:if>
                           <br>
                       </h5>

                           <p><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.content}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.content}" /></c:if></p>

                           <h4><b><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.heading1}">
                            <c:out value="${tutoriallist.heading1}" /></c:if></b></h4>

                           <p><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.content1}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.content1}" /></c:if></p>

                           <h4><b><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.heading2}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.heading2}" /></c:if></b></h4>

                           <p><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.content2}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.content2}" /></c:if></p>

                           <h4><b><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.heading3}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.heading3}" /></c:if></b></h4>

                           <p><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.content3}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.content3}" /></c:if></p>

                           <h4><b><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.heading4}">
                           <c:out value="${tutoriallist.heading4}" /></c:if></b></h4>

                           <p><c:if test="${not empty tutoriallist.content4}">
                           <pre><c:out value="${tutoriallist.content4}" /></pre></c:if></p>
   </tr></tbody></table>
   </div></div></div></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: have you tried to add `a:active` css ? like `a:active{color: red}`

Comment: yes use this only the color changing at the time of clicking but when the link opens it gets disappears.

Comment: Try `a:visited` then

Comment: no not working, can you suggest the javascript to use for this.actually we are fetching the links dynamically not statically you can check my code.

Comment: are you redirecting to same tab with anchor tags and want to highlight the clicked anchor tag after page redirects?

Comment: yes i want to highlight the clicked link.

Comment: Can you add your page output also? right now i can only suggest you to add some param to anchor href and then on master page load check that param to identify which anchor tag was clicked and then just add class to that

Comment: _“I think have some javascript problem in my code”_ - then provide your JS code, so that we can see what is going on. (Also, please provide a _proper_ testable [mcve]. Your code as shown contains server-side coding, that none of us here have the server-side setup for available - so please provide the actual rendered HTML output instead.) _“so please provide the css and javascript”_ - no, the purpose of this site is not to write the code for you.